# Environtment variable not show in rails c

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, environment-variables, schema.yml

I wanna ask about ruby on rails, 
Environment variable can be set using application.yml

I have a code like this in application.yml

```
defaults: &defaults
  STORE_URL: https://localhost:3000/

development:
  <<: *defaults

test:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults
```

and also set the configuration on application.rb

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

if File.exists?(File.expand_path('../application.yml', __FILE__))
  config = YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../application.yml', __FILE__)))
  config.merge! config.fetch(Rails.env, {})
  config.each do |key, value|
    ENV[key] ||= value.to_s unless value.kind_of? Hash
  end
end
```

and add this code to .gitignore

```
config/appication.yml
.project
```

the output should be like this when i test it on terminal,

```
[1] pry(main)> ENV
=> {"Test1"=>"Tester1",
    "Test2"=>"Tester2",
    "Test3"=>"Tester3"}
```

It should just add some a Key and Value when i `run rails c development`

In Rails 3.0.20 and Ruby 1.9.3p545 it work so simple when i tested it by type or adding new Key and Value on application.yml .but, on Rails 4.1.5 and Ruby 2.0.0p541 it wont goes like that

Full Application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

if File.exists?(File.expand_path('../application.yml', __FILE__))
  config = YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../application.yml', __FILE__)))
  config.merge! config.fetch(Rails.env, {})
  config.each do |key, value|
    ENV[key] ||= value.to_s unless value.kind_of? Hash
  end
end

module ModuleUpgrade
  class Application < Rails::Application
  end
end
```

Need Your Help Guys!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would change two things. How you load the file and how you fetch and merge the sub hash for the environment:

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

file = Rails.root.join('config', 'application.yml')
if File.exists?(file)
  config = YAML.load(file).fetch(Rails.env, {})
  config.each do |key, value|
    ENV[key] ||= value unless value.kind_of?(Hash)
  end
end
```

Comment: set up in application.yml, and it will show when i test in rails c and type ENV. @spickermann

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand what you want to say.

Comment: yeah me too.. i'm new with ruby on rails. so i just guessing what u mean. @spickermann

Comment: i try ur code but i got an error with `join` 
`<top (required)>': undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` @spickermann

Comment: It seems like you try to load your code before Rails is loaded. That is a problem, because later on you call `Rails.env` which is also be nil. You should run that code later, perhaps put is in `config/initializers/env.rb`?

Comment: Ok i'll try., u mean put application.rb on config/initializers.rb @spickermann

Comment: I already tried to put env.rb in config/initializers/ when i put key and value into the env.yml its only read once. i try to put again it doesn't work when i test it on rails c @spickermann

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the path you've specified for `application.yml`, `File.expand_path('../application.yml', __FILE__)`, is accurate. Try this:

```
app_config = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'application.yml')
if File.exists?(app_config)
  config = YAML.load(File.read(app_config))
  config.merge! config.fetch(Rails.env, {})
  config.each do |key, value|
    ENV[key] ||= value.to_s unless value.kind_of? Hash
  end
end
```

Alternatively the [figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) attempts to make this easier for you if you don't want to roll it yourself.

Comment: I already tried but got an error.
`config/application.rb:9:in `join': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)`
@glenn-gillen

Comment: That means `Rails.root` is nil, which probably means Rails itself hasn't been loaded yet. Can you paste your full `application.rb` file in here?

Comment: I need to amended version which includes my change, the error shouldn't be on line #9 if it was a straight substitution.